# Possessive of already possessive proper noun!

Tags: possessives, proper-nouns

I was wondering how to write the possessive form of a proper noun that is already in a possessive form (confusing, I know...)
My company's name is Tuc's Contracting. If I were to write the possessive form of that, it would be Tuc's Contracting's. My question is if I were to leave off the "Contracting's" part, how would I write the possessive form of Tuc's (which is a proper noun already in a possessive form...HELP!) 
The proper noun is not “Tuc” it is “Tuc’s” so that is where I am confused…
Tuc's?
Tucs'?
Tuc's'?
The proper noun is not “Tuc” it is “Tuc’s” so that is where I am confused…
None of these seem right to me...And that is why I am seeking your expertise! 
Thank you :)

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a full sample sentence please?

Comment: What's the context? Is this a contract, or something more casual like a brochure?

Comment: I'm almost certain this question has been asked before. Here it is asked on ELL: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31242/possessive-of-a-possessive.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting dilemma! I believe you are safe just using "Tuc's". Look at articles written about McDonald's and you'll see the formatting doesn't change in possessive instances (e.g., McDonald's business model is...)